# How can we scan our range of ports efficiently?

Tags: firewall, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a script that will check if my firewall works correctly.

For that I need a command that checks our range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the nmap command

```
sudo nmap -sT remote_host
```

For more information https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nmap-to-scan-for-open-ports-on-your-vps

Comment: NMAP is the tool for this, I agree. The thing is you have to run it from _outside_ your network to see what is happening at the firewall. So just get on public Wi-Fi with a Mac or Linux machine, open terminal and run: `nmap -A (your public IP)`
Worth noting that if you have an IPS or IDS at the gateway it may see this as "hacking" so be sure to notify appropriate personnel you're doing this.